# IdentityModel.AspNetCore problem with proxy credentials for backchannel HttpClient

Tags: .net-core, proxy, access-token, dotnet-httpclient, identitymodel

I'm using [IdentityModel.AspNetCore](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore) to manage client access tokens in a background service. Access to the internet is only possible through a corporate proxy server which uses windows authentication.

The proxy server is configured in Windows options and the background service detects the settings, however authentication doesn't work and I'm constantly getting `The proxy tunnel request to proxy 'http://proxy:8080/' failed with status code '407'`. How can I configure the HttpClient to use the windows credentials for authentication against the proxy server?

I've already tried the following, but this doesn't work:

```csharp
        services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
        {
            options.Client.Clients.Add("sapci", new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
            {
                Address = hostContext.Configuration["HttpProxy:TokenEndpoint"],
                ClientId = hostContext.Configuration["HttpProxy:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = hostContext.Configuration["HttpProxy:ClientSecret"],
                GrantType = OidcConstants.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                AuthorizationHeaderStyle = BasicAuthenticationHeaderStyle.Rfc2617,
                ClientCredentialStyle = ClientCredentialStyle.AuthorizationHeader
            });
        })
        .ConfigureBackchannelHttpClient(client => new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
        }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this at app startup, to ensure you capture all client usages:

```cs
HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy()
{
  Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
}:
```

I would reduce your problem to deploying a minimal console app and running it with the same user account etc as your service. Once that works your main app will also.

Sometimes these things are infrastructure related also: eg in the past, with IIS clustered environments, I've had to use a service account and register a service principal name, eg to prevent use of computer accounts. I doubt that is relevant to .Net Core / Kestrel though, which I assume you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I already have checked infrastructure or local client related issues as you suggested. Setting a static `DefaultProxy` in `HttpClient` works. Would be interesting to tackle down the root cause, possibly inside IdentityModel.AspNetCore HttpClientHandler chain.